# Errors when using react-digraph with VueJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

I'm trying to use [react-digraph](https://github.com/uber/react-digraph) to create a UI tool to manage parent-child hierarchies from DB.
Graphs should be interactive and editable, also a child can have multiple parents. I've looked at different libraries online and react-digraph seemed to me the best fit for the task. Please let me know if you are aware of better options.
The current problem is that our UI stack is mostly VueJS. So, I set up a testing project with Vue CLI (TypeScript included). Then I installed react-digraph and [veaury](https://github.com/devilwjp/veaury) (library which seems to make React components work in Vue), however I'm getting following errors:
[image]
I would appreciate your help if you share your knowledge on the solution.
So, my current dependencies in the package.json look like this:

```json
"core-js": "^3.6.5",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-digraph": "^8.1.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"veaury": "^2.3.11",
"vue": "^3.0.0",
"vue-class-component": "^8.0.0-0",
"vuex": "^4.0.0-0"
```

And here is my GraphEditor.vue:

```js
<template>
  <div style="height: 500px; width: 100%; background-color: black">
    <Graph
      :nodeKey="nodeKey"
      :nodes="nodes"
      :edges="edges"
      :selected="selected"
      :nodeTypes="graphConfig.NodeTypes"
      :nodeSubtypes="graphConfig.NodeSubTypes"
      :edgeTypes="graphConfig.EdgeTypes"
      :allowMultiselect="true"
      @onSelect="emptyFunc"
      @onCreateNode="emptyFunc"
      @onUpdateNode="emptyFunc"
      @onDeleteNode="emptyFunc"
      @onCreateEdge="emptyFunc"
      @onSwapEdge="emptyFunc"
      @onDeleteEdge="emptyFunc"
    />
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Options, Vue } from "vue-class-component";
import { applyPureReactInVue } from "veaury";
import { GraphView } from "react-digraph";
import { ref } from "vue";

@Options({
  components: {
    Graph: applyPureReactInVue(GraphView),
  },
})
export default class GraphEditor extends Vue {
  private nodeKey = "id";
  private graphConfig = {
    NodeTypes: {
      empty: {
        // required to show empty nodes
        typeText: "None",
        shapeId: "#empty", // relates to the type property of a node
        shape: ref(
          '<symbol viewBox="0 0 100 100" id="empty" key="0"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45"></circle></symbol>'
        ),
      },
      custom: {
        // required to show empty nodes
        typeText: "Custom",
        shapeId: "#custom", // relates to the type property of a node
        shape: ref(
          '<symbol viewBox="0 0 50 25" id="custom" key="0"><ellipse cx="50" cy="25" rx="50" ry="25"></ellipse></symbol>'
        ),
      },
    },
    NodeSubtypes: {},
    EdgeTypes: {
      emptyEdge: {
        // required to show empty edges
        shapeId: "#emptyEdge",
        shape: ref(
          '<symbol viewBox="0 0 50 50" id="emptyEdge" key="0"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="8" fill="currentColor">{" "}</circle></symbol>'
        ),
      },
    },
  };

  private emptyFunc(e: any) {
    console.log();
  }

  private nodes = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Node A",
      x: 258.3976135253906,
      y: 331.9783248901367,
      type: "empty",
    }
  ];
  private edges = [];
  private selected = [];
}
</script>
<style scoped lang="scss"></style>
```

Comment: If you want that hard to mix both React and Vue, you are probably better off using something like Astro. Otherwise, I recommend splitting the various tools to better narrow down where the issue is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Owner of veaury library was able to give me good recommendations, so I've built a working solution for this problem here: https://github.com/algouser2/react-digraph-vuejs